# Trouble sending email through contact form with php

Tags: php, html

I've never worked with php before and am trying to make my contact form functional with the help of some php code I acquired through google.

First off do I need to link it to my html page somehow (like css/ javascript) or does it work fine if it shares the same folder?

I have modified the names of certain parts to match the names in my html but am unable to get it to work. When I click the submit button I get a page saying...

```
"; exit; } // prepare email body text $Body = ""; $Body .= "Name: "; $Body .= $Name; $Body .= "\n"; $Body .= "Company: "; $Body .= $Company; $Body .= "\n"; $Body .= "Email: "; $Body .= $Email; $Body .= "\n"; $Body .= "Deadline: "; $Body .= $Dealine; $Body .= "\n"; $Body .= "Interested: "; $Body .= $Interested; $Body .= "\n"; $Body .= "Message: "; $Body .= $Message; $Body .= "\n"; // send email $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>"); // redirect to success page if ($success){ print ""; } else{ print ""; } ?>
```

The php code is as follows.

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "c@c.co.nz";
$EmailTo = "c@c.co.nz";
$Subject = "contact-form";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Company = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Company'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Deadline = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Dealine'])); 
$Interested = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Interested'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Company: ";
$Body .= $Company;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Deadline: ";
$Body .= $Dealine;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Interested: ";
$Body .= $Interested;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";


// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contact-thanks.php\">";
}
else{
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

Here is my html

```
    <div role="form" class="form-wrapper">
<form name="contact-f" action="contact-form.php" method="post">
<div class="f-width">
<div class="f-col-1 f-group-1"><input type="text" name="Name" class="c-back input-t f-col-1" placeholder="Name" /></div>
<div class="f-col-1 f-group-2"><input type="email" name="Company" class="c-back input-t f-col-1" placeholder="Company Name" /></div>
<div class="f-col-1 f-group-1"><input type="text" name="Email" class="c-back input-t f-col-1" placeholder="Email Address" /></div>
<div class="f-col-1 f-group-2"><select name="Deadline" class="c-back input-t f-col-1"><option class="opt-f">Do you have a Deadline?</option><option value="Not yet" class="opt-f">Not yet</option><option value="Less than 1 Month" class="opt-f">Less than 1 Month</option><option value="2-3 Months" class="opt-f">2-3 Months</option><option value="3-6 Months" class="opt-f">3-6 Months</option><option value="6+ Months" class="opt-f">6+ Months</option></select></div>
<div class="f-col-2 f-group-3"><select name="Interested" class="c-back input-t f-col-2"><option class="opt-f">What are you interested in?</option><option value="Branding" class="opt-f">Branding</option><option value="Print Design" class="opt-f">Print Design</option><option value="Illustration" class="opt-f">Illustration</option><option value="Website / UI Design" class="opt-f">Website / UI Design</option><option value="Literature" class="opt-f">Literature</option><option value="Video Editing" class="opt-f">Video Editing</option><option value="Other" class="opt-f">Other</option></select></div>
<div class="f-col-3 f-group-4"><textarea name="Message" class="c-back input-t message-f f-col-3" placeholder="Describe your project..."></textarea></div>
<div class="f-submit f-group-5"><input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Send" class="form-btn" /></div>
</div></form></div>
```

(And yes I have created the contact-thanks.php file it calls for at the end).

Comment: This PHP script here - does the file name end in .php or .html?

Comment: Also does it matter what properties as in the form tag in the html apart from the action.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me as-is so the problem isn't with your PHP file. You should go through the steps in the question Paul Crovella linked to.

Answer (score 0):

So many $Body , How About :

```
$Body = " Name : $Name \n Company : $Company \n Deadline : $Deadline \n Interested : $Interested \n Message : $Message";
```

Is This What You Looking For ?

Comment: Still comes up with the same error just with fewer words. Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: What Does The Error Say ? Tell Us (Me Exactly)

Comment: Once I click the submit button it directs me to a blank page with most of the php text (The first line of code in the original question).

Comment: you didn't give us the form code . . . there ' s an error at there too

Comment: Form code is up :)

Comment: missed a lot code ... let me fix give me a min

Comment: give me a more min

Comment: Thanks for your time man, I really appreciate it.